# Product of compacts is compacts using closedness of projection to second component?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, compactness

A well known characterization of compactness says $X$ is compact iff for all spaces $Y$ the projection $X\times Y\rightarrow Y$ is a closed map.

I'm wondering whether there's some simple formal way to prove a (finite?) product of compacts is compact using this characterization.

Let $X,Y$ be compact. Starting with $\pi _X:X\times Z\rightarrow Z,\pi _Y:Y\times Z\rightarrow Z$, which we know are closed, how can we move (categorically) to $\pi_{X\times Y}:(X\times Y)\times Z\rightarrow Z$ and show it's closed?

**Added.** Just to clarify - I'm looking for a *formal* (categorical as possible) way to prove this. So far the most elegant proof I can think of uses the fact a closed map with compact fibers is proper:

*Short proof.* If $X$ is compact, $\pi:X\times Y\rightarrow Y$ is closed (tube lemma). The fibers of $\pi$ are all homeomorphic to $X$ and hence are all compact, therefore $\pi$ is proper. If $Y$ is compact, so must be it's preimage, $X\times Y$.

Comment: Another way to prove the closedness of the projection is the following:
Each projection $\pi_X,\pi_Y$ is a closed map with compact fibers (such a map is called *perfect*). The projection $X\times Y\times Z\to Z$ can be factored as
$$
X×Y×Z \xrightarrow{1_X×\pi_Y} X×Z \xrightarrow{\pi_X} Z
$$
Now a perfect has the property that its product with any identity map is perfect as well. Therefore both maps in the sequence are closed and so is their composite.

Comment: This can also be used to show that a perfect map is proper. Note that if $f:X\to Y$ is perfect, then so is its restriction $f^{-1}(A)\to A$ for any subset $A$ of $Y$. So it suffices to show that $X$ is compact when $Y$ is compact.

It is enough to show that $\pi_X:X×Z\to Z$ is closed for an arbitrary $Z$. The projection can be factored as
$$
X×Z \xrightarrow{f×1_Z} Y\times Z \xrightarrow{\pi_Z} Z
$$
The first map is closed as noted in the comment, and the second map is due to the compactness of $Y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us say that a continuous map $f : X \to S$ is **universally closed** if, for every continuous map $g : Y \to S$, the projection $\{ (x, y) \in X \times Y : f (x) = g (y) \} \to Y$ is closed. The characterisation of compactness you allude to is this:

> A topological space $X$ is compact if and only if the unique map $X \to 1$ is universally closed.

It is easy to verify the following:

> - The class of universally closed maps is closed under pullback.
> - The class of universally closed maps is closed under composition.

(Use the pullback pasting lemma.)

We obtain the following corollary:

> - The class of universally closed maps is closed under binary product.

Indeed, given universally closed maps $f_0 : X_0 \to S_0$ and $f_1 : X_1 \to S_1$, we have the following pullback diagrams,
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_0 \times X_1 @>>> X_0 \\
@V{f_0 \times \mathrm{id}_{X_1}}VV @VV{f_0}V \\
S_0 \times X_1 @>>> S_0
\end{CD}$$
$$\begin{CD}
S_0 \times X_1 @>>> X_1 \\
@V{\mathrm{id}_{S_0} \times f_1}VV @VV{f_1}V \\
S_0 \times S_1 @>>> S_1
\end{CD}$$
so by taking the composite of the left vertical arrows, it follows that $f_0 \times f_1 : X_0 \times X_1 \to S_0 \times S_1$ is universally closed. In particular, the product of two compact topological spaces is compact.

Incidentally, universally closed maps are the same as proper maps.

Comment: Elegant answer! When you write 'proper' do you mean pulling back compacts to compacts?

Comment: There are variations in the terminology. Here, I mean a closed (continuous) map such that the inverse image of a compact subspace is compact. It is the same as what Stefan Hamcke calls "perfect".

Comment: Is the continuity really necessary here? For instance, the proof that a perfect map pulls back compacts to compacts does not rely on continuity. In particular, can all these pullbacks be taken in the category of sets (forget only continuity, not the topologies of course)?

Comment: Everything in my post goes through for not-necessarily-continuous closed maps.